# How can I generate a narrowband spectra from command line?

Tags: audio, python3

Is there a Linux command line tool to generate energy averaged narrowband spectra using the Hann window? I would like to do a spectra from audio from wind turbines. The specs says the following:

```
The two one-minute measurements shall be divided into 12 ten-second periods, 
from which 12 energy averaged narrowband spectra using the Hanning window
are obtained.
```

and

```
The bandwidth of a critical band shall be determined by 

    critical bandwidth = 25+75(1+1,4[f_c/1000])^0,69

where f_c is the center frequency in HZ.
```

I think the Hanning window here means the Hann window as in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hanning.html. I found there is a tool called spek but as I tried to compile it, it said

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libavcodec >= 53.25 libavformat >= 53.17 libavutil >= 51.17) were not met:

No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libavformat' found
No package 'libavutil' found
```

Then I tried

```
sudo apt install libavformat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libavformat
```

Comment: I can't be sure but IMO you should start here https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/chains_for_batch_processing_and_effects_automation.html

Comment: Thanks for that but I think Audacity won't fit for my needs. I read from https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=7220 : "Audacity has been designed to be used with a GUI."